# PC won't post after GPU replacement

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply

I just replaced my GPU from a RX580 to 1660 Super.
It won't boot, nothing on the screen. Even after replacing the GPU back, and removing it.

Lights are on, Fans spinning (both GPU and CPU). But no HDD light. PC stays on but no boot or post.

I'm suspecting I might have hurt the PCI pins, but I have no way of telling.

Someone told me the PSU might have been hurt somehow.

I tried unplugging the power, removing the battery, cleaning the PCI with a tissue. Holding the power button for 20 seconds. Nothing.

Other components :

I5-8600k

16 GBs RAM 2400 MHz

500 Watt FPS PSU

Comment: Unsure if "Even after replacing the GPU back, and removing it." means putting the RX580 back in, and then swapping the 1660 back in. If not, have you tried booting with the original graphics card? Can you get into the BIOS? Any POST beeps?

Comment: Can you try removing the graphics card and using the integrating graphics?

Comment: @spikey_richie yes, putting the RX580 back, and even removing the GPU and using the integrated one. Still the same. My motherboard doesn't have a beep thing

Comment: Another possibility is that you fried your mainboard. Did you unplug every cable when replacing the card? Some cheap USB hubs feed power into the mainboard when they are connected to a wall socket for extra power. Hope that it's just the PSU.